# ParseTreeVisitor or ParseTreeListener

Tags: java, antlr

I am trying to write an AST interpreter / REPL.  ANTLRv4 provides two very similar interfaces ([ParseTreeVisitor](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeVisitor.html) and [ParseTreeListener](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeListener.html)) to walk the parse tree.  I cannot seem to find any major differences between them, and the documentation is rather sparse.  Is one interface preferable to the other?

Comment: While `Visitor` returns values, `Listener` doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interfaces are used for different purposes. The primary differences are as follows:

`ParseTreeListener`

- Provides *separate* enter/exit methods for *before/after* the children of a parse tree node are examined.
- All methods return `void`. Any values collected for "return" by the listener must be held in fields or elsewhere.
- Control of which tree nodes are examined is *external* (via `ParseTreeWalker` or a derived class).

`ParseTreeVisitor`

- Provides *one* method which is responsible for *all* analysis/behavior for each parse tree node.
- Each method returns generic type parameter `T`, which may be `Void` if the visitor methods do not return a value.
- Control of which tree nodes are examined is *internal* (via `visitChildren` and/or calls to `visit` for specific children).